# A question about the dual space of the subspace of Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

Suppose we have a Hilbert Space $X$, with a Hilbert subspace $H \subset X$.

For each $f \in X^*$, we can restrict it on $H$, as a consequence we have $X^* \subset H^*$; and the two dual space here are not equivalent in general.

But as a corollary of Rietz representation theorem, there is a isomorphism between $X$ and $X^*$, $H$ and $H^*$. In other words, we can treat the element $h \in H$ as an element in $H^*$, by using $h(u) = (h|u)$. We can prove that this is the form of any element in $H^*$;

In all, we have the seemingly controversial result as 
$$ H \subset X = X^* \subset H^* = H$$

What's wrong with this? Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2):

The morphism $X^*\rightarrow H^*$ is not always injective. Take $x$ orthogonal to $H$, and $f(x)=\langle x,.\rangle$. The restriction of $f_x$ to $H$ is zero. So $X^*$ is not imbedded in $H^*$.

Comment: So what do we want to say when we write "$X^* \subset H^*$"

Comment: @Kepler There is a linear injection $i : H \rightarrow X$. It has an adjoint map $i^* : X^* \rightarrow H^*$, that isn't injective in general. We can take an element of $X^*$, which is a linear form on $X$, and restrict its domain to $H$, making an element of $H^*$ (this is exactly what $i^*$ does). We can't just write $X^* \subset H^*$.